# multiple instances of named argument in list

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I'm getting this error in ASP.NET application (whereas it works fine in Oracle)

**PLS-00703::multiple instances of named argument in list**

I've attached the code here. It shows error in the last line i.e. *cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()*

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_prog_id", 2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_sllr_co_id", 1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_sllr_purch_loc_nbr", 1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_byr_co_id", Convert.ToInt32(co_id));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_byr_purch_loc_nbr", purch_loc_nbr);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_ing_id", ing_id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_per_id", per_id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_ing_purch_qty", "12");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_pop_sl_trck_nbr", "ECAP");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_pop_sl_cmnt_txt",  dstemp.Tables["ECAP"].Rows[i][6].ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_chg_by", 1333);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_ing_rev_amt", dstemp.Tables["ECAP"].Rows[i][5].ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_sl_typ", "ME");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_dir_sale_ind", "DIR-SL");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("in_intg_sl_ind", "N");  ***//character as input***
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is my method inside which the above statements hold in.

```
private void call_proc(int i, DataSet dstemp, OracleCommand cmd)
{


}
```

and I invoke this method as follows:

```
    cmd1 = conn3.CreateCommand();
    cmd1.CommandText = "pkg_sale.cre_pop_sl";
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["ECAP"].Rows.Count; ++i)
        call_proc(i, ds, cmd1);
```

Is there any problem in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a common error with Oracle stored procedures and the most common cause is that the developer neglected to call `Parameters.Clear` before repeated invocation of the code.

Either that, or one or more of your parameters is being repeated someplace else.

**Edit (after OP's post)**

It appears to be the first possibility because you are calling the function in a loop. Just Clear the parameters within the looped function and it should work.

See [this reference](http://www.error-code.org.uk/view.asp?e=ORACLE-PLS-00703)

Answer (score 1):

Are you reusing the instance in `cmd` for multiple SQL statements perhaps?

There's no duplicates in what you've posted here so I doubt this code alone is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across another scenario where this could happen if you are using ODP.Net. If you are using any utility classes to generate your command (Like I do in my project), it could be doing some 'smart' work behind the scene to derive parameters from the stored procedure.

```
 OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters((OracleCommand)command);
```

This statement injects the parameters in to the Command object and if you add your parameters to the same cmd object (Like you would normally do) it will have 2 parameters with the same name.